# Props not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When clicking a button i have an event error, the problem is i dont know how to convert this with hooks

```
const Header = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  function handleChange(event, newValue) {
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  function onLogoutClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  }

  //this.onLogoutClick = this.onLogoutClick.bind(this);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="sticky">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} centered>
          {" "}
          {/* <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                {sections.map(section => (
                  <Tab label={section} />
                ))}
              </Tabs> */}{" "}
          <Tab label="Indicadores Globais" />
          <Tab label="Indicadores Colaboradores" />
          <Tab label="Indicadores Produto" />
          <Tab label="Indicadores Temporais" />
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.classesButton}
            onClick={onLogoutClick}
          >
            Logout
          </Button>
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined when clicking on the button. I know the problem is on the onClick={onLogoutClick} but im not sure how to solve this. Any help?

Comment: you need to remove `this.` and receive props as an argument to the function

Comment: Function `Header` needs Props in params like : 
`const Header = props => ( /* code */ )`
and in your function `onLogoutClick ` you can call `props. logoutUser()``

Comment: Did you try to bind this to you function? Something like this in 
<Button
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.classesButton}
            onClick={onLogoutClick.bind(this)}
          >
or in constructor
this.onLogoutClick = this.onLogoutClick.bind(this)

Answer (score 2):

An event handler will override `this` in the callback with the event object. To make sure the component is scoped in the callback, you need to bind it to the function.

```
<Button
    color="inherit"
    className={classes.classesButton}
    onClick={onLogoutClick.bind(this)}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

this inside onLogoutClick points to the html element. If you want to access the component as this, You need to bind the action with this.

```
<Button
    color="inherit"
    className={classes.classesButton}
    onClick={onLogoutClick.bind(this)}
>
```

But this is not the recommended method as it binds this with action every time component renders. The recommended method is to bind the action with this in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.onLogoutClick = this.onLogoutClick.bind(this);
 }
```